# Hippo CMS (Bloomreach) On initial setup, essentials page gives a 404

Tags: hippocms

I'm following the [Get Started section (v13)](https://documentation.bloomreach.com/trails/getting-started/hippo-essentials-getting-started.html) in the Bloomreach documentation, and unable to proceed, as the essentials page on my project gives me a 404. <strike>I think I've done everything word for word.</strike> (Obviously I did not. I apparently glazed over the Java spec, assuming a recent version was good. Anyhow, if anyone makes the same mistake, maybe this will help.)

http://localhost:8080/cms/ works as expected. I can log in and all.

I'm running this on OS X Mojave 10.14.4. Maven 3.6.1. Java 12.0.1.

This is the page I am stuck on because of this, where it calls out navigating to the essentials page: https://documentation.bloomreach.com/trails/getting-started/adding-features-to-a-project.html

Version 12.1 doesn't give me the error from the server, but I get "This localhost page can’t be found" from Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation it states that you need Java version 8. I installed JDK 1.8.0_212, and everything started working. I previously had Java 12.x.

Comment: Good that you found the issue. Unfortunately we are still on Java 8. It isn't a trivial thing to move to a newer version and sometimes stability is more important.